# django values not working

Tags: django, django-queryset

When I try to call values with more than 3 fields it seems to 'break' (ie. it doesn't group duplicate entries together)

My model is a through model with three fields, 2 `ForeignKey` and one `DateTimeField`

```
ProjectView(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  datetime_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to do:

```
ProjectView.objects.filter(datetime_created__gt=yesterday).values('project__id', 'project__title', 'project__thumbnail', 'project__creator_username')
```

If i get rid of any one of the values fields it groups them by same projects without duplicates, if there are 4 values it seems to do no grouping. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can't you just access the Project object values via relationships? Like `proj_view.project.id` or `proj_view.project.title`?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) for values, you'll see no guarantee of grouping or distinct. If you want that functionality, you'll have to call `.order_by()` and/or `.distinct()` when making you call to the ORM.

That it works at all is probably just a side effect of the SQL generated. If you want to see the SQL, take a look at Django-debug-toolbar

Comment: does .group_by() work in the latest version of django? It seems like it's not implemented...

Comment: It's actually order_by and not group_by